# django tags spanning multiple lines

Tags: django, django-templates

I was following a django tutorial and I noticed the string text kept having \ in it. I thought that simulated \n in django... Then for some reason tags wouldn't render correctly.

Context: sending an email through sendgrid from a generated template
For example:

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% trans "Hi" %} {{ user.get_username }},

{% trans "We've received a request to reset your password. If you didn't 
make\ this request, you can safely ignore this email. Otherwise, click the 
button\ below to reset your password." %}

{% block reset_link %}
    {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid \
token=token %}
{% endblock reset_link %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

got this in the email:

{% trans "We've received a request to reset your password. If you didn't make\
this request, you can safely ignore this email. Otherwise, click the button\
below to reset your password." %}

http://127.0.0.1:8000{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid\
token=token %}

but this rendered the email correctly:

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% trans "Hi" %} {{ user.get_username }},

{% trans "We've received a request to reset your password. If you didn't 
make this request, you can safely ignore this email. Otherwise, click the 
button below to reset your password." %}

{% block reset_link %}
    {{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid   token=token %}
{% endblock reset_link %}
{% endautoescape %}
```

so can anyone elaborate on why the other would do something like this? because from my understanding line break is done like this: {{ value|linebreaksbr }}
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks

Comment: The \ character allows for a lign break in the python code to make it easier readable but is ignored aside from that. \n is a line break in a string.

Comment: Can you explain then why using the \ in the first example caused it not to render correctly in the email if it is ignored?

Comment: Backslash is ignored (used for line continuation) only in python (`*.py`) files. It is not ignored in template files.